# Strong yet simple Rails authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

My authentication system will be at the heart of my application and the revenue model for my business. I want a strong, but yet simple authentication option for Rails.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have many different authentification options for Rails.
I personaly prefer Devise, it's really complete, with a lot of features and simple to use.
You can have a look at a Railscast :
http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Answer (score 0):

Use [facebook for websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) to authenticate use. There is one one gem which lets you use facebook auth via devise (devise_facebook_connectable)
https://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable